# excel heading as primary keys in sql server database table

Tags: sql-server

problem is i wants to select excel sheet header from excel file and match header column with table primary key and update the require fields according to excel heading columns.
so far i tried to import excel file in sql server but excel header not import in my table so there is any solutions to direct select header from excel file and update my table.
basically i wants like this
update table set column=(select

```
   SELECT *  FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
  'Excel 8.0;Database=I:\test.xls;HDR=No',)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This excel cannot be directly imported using Import/Export wizard if you say that the first row is the primary key for your SQL table. First import the excel data in a DataTable using the following code below:

```
public class ExcelRow
    {
        List<object> columns;

        public ExcelRow()
        {
            columns = new List<object>();
        }

        internal void AddColumn(object value)
        {
            columns.Add(value);
        }

        public object this[int index]
        {
            get { return columns[index]; }
        }

        public string GetString(int index)
        {
            if (columns[index] is DBNull)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return columns[index].ToString();
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return this.columns.Count; }
        }
    }

    public class ExcelProvider:IEnumerable<ExcelRow>
    {
        private string sheet;
        private string filePath;
        private List<ExcelRow> rows;


        public ExcelProvider()
        {
            rows = new List<ExcelRow>();
        }

        public static ExcelProvider Create(string filePath, string sheet)
        {
            ExcelProvider provider = new ExcelProvider();
            provider.sheet = sheet;
            provider.filePath = filePath;
            return provider;
        }

        private void Load()
        {
            string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=    ""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
            rows.Clear();
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select * from [" + sheet + "$]";
                    using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            ExcelRow newRow = new ExcelRow();
                            for(int count = 0; count < reader.FieldCount; count++) {
                                newRow.AddColumn(reader[count]);
                            }
                            rows.Add(newRow);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator<ExcelRow> GetEnumerator()
        {
            Load();
            return rows.GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            Load();
            return rows.GetEnumerator();
        }

    }

public DataTable GetDataTableFromExcel()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            ExcelProvider objProvider = ExcelProvider.Create(@"Your excel file path", "TableExtract");

            dt.Columns.Add("AA");
            /* Add other columns here */

            foreach (ExcelRow row in (from x in objProvider select x))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(row.GetString(0));
            }

            return dt;
        }
```

Then process the data in the data table to insert it into the database using the first row as the primary key for each insertion using a backend stored procedure for insertion.