# Update values in the SQL table from a file

Tags: mysql, sql

Help me please.
I have a table: **"table"**.

It has columns: **ID | FirstName | LastName | Key**.

The value of the **"key"** sometimes changes.

How to change the value "KEY" taking the values "FirstName", "LastName" from the excel file?
Regards

Comment: Stackoverflow search "Excel update MySQL" -> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Excel+update+MySQL ... "Excel export MySQL" -> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Excel+export+MySQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [excel heading as primary keys in sql server database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295164/excel-heading-as-primary-keys-in-sql-server-database-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the excel file as a table to your MySQL database. Than it is easy to write a conditional update statement.

https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/export/MySQLforExcelExportData.png

Or you can create update statements in excel file with using excel string addition operator and run these statements in your database. The concatenate formula would look like;

```
="update table  set key = '..' where name =  '" &B3 &"' and lastname ='"&D3&"';"
```

The final queries will look like:

update table  set key = '..' where name =  'name1' and lastname 'lastname';

Comment: A little bit wrong. I can not connect an Excel to a DB (security policy company). I need to get data from excel (FirstName, Lastname) and change the value  "KEY" for these records at db

Comment: i have added another option to achieve this. @NickSemenov